# Can you please explaine my code on cypress ? There is getting worse result error 500

Tags: automated-tests, cypress

Please help me to fixing my automation testing project with cypress. I trying to submit login form with this code on cypress project:

```
`it('submit form', function(){

    cy.get('[type="submit"]')
      .click({force :true})
      .wait(1000)
})`
```

And then i found this result on my project :

element website:
[image: element website]

result error 500:
[image: result error 500]

console-log:
[image: console-log]

On another side, my friend told me, he successfully clicking login button using selenium without 500 server error. When i make something wrong in my code? please explaine to me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this has something to do with Cypress but an issue with the actual website itself. The description on the error on the website is clearly stating that it is over capacity. Although stranger things have happened so try choosing another browser (Electron, Firefox) found at the upper right side of the Cypress runner.

It would also be useful if you can show the Console logs or the Network error via the Chrome Devtools. You can do this by doing a right-click on the website then navigate to **Inspect > Console** or **Inspect > Network**

===

This code works:

```
const username = 'test@test.com'
const password = 'test1234'

describe('Log on to Pricebook', ()=> {
    it('Log on to Pricebook', () => {
        cy.visit('https://www.pricebook.co.id/login')
            .get('[name="email"]')
            .type(username)
            .get('[name="password"]')
            .type(password, {log: false})

        cy.get('[data-track-action="login-button"]').click()
    }) 
})
```

Comment: Hi ebanster, i'm already to trying with manual tester and my friend was tried with selenium too and it's working properly, so are you sure this issue from website itself ? I don't know to debugging it, can u please check my newly attachment.

Comment: Best practice is to use a unique CSS Selector. There could be multiple elements with `type=submit`. Also, try to avoid implicit waits especially with Cypress. In any case, try to clear your cookies. Cypress has a native command `cy.clearCookies()` too. See my code above using a different CSS selector (I have updated my answer) and that simple test works in Chrome 80 and Edge.

Comment: Awesome! thanks your code very useful for implement

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
Cypress open
```

then you can use cypress tool to retrive element.

[Cypres printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vYUN.png)